# egrep search with or(|) and tab(\t) not work

Tags: regex, grep

there is a file have below content,

```
➜  ~  cat foo
123 456
1234    1234
123456789   12345678
123456789   12345678
12345678901234567890    12345678901234567890
```

and only first column is 9 digit(`\d{9}`) is valid, so I want to grep those invalid lines, first I tried below command and it does not work

```
➜  ~   cat foo | egrep  $'^[0-9]{1,8}\t.*$ | ^[0-9]{10,}\t.*$'
```

nothing output.

Then I tried below command, this time it works

```
➜  ~   cat foo | egrep  -v $'^[0-9]{9}\t.*$'
123 456
1234    1234
12345678901234567890    12345678901234567890
```

So why first command not work, where is wrong? How could let it works too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need brackets around your alternate options:

```
egrep  '(^[0-9]{1,8}[[:space:]].*$)|(^[0-9]{10,}[[:space:]].*$)' foo
```

But really, your second expression makes more sense. Search for lines that don't contain 9 numbers, rather than lines that contain 1-8 numbers, or 10 or more numbers. Also, `grep` can accept a file name argument; there's no need to use `cat`.

It seems like this is what you're looking for:

```
egrep -v "^[0-9]{9}[[:space:]]" foo
```

Comment: Thanks! but use `egrep  $'(^[0-9]{1,8}\t.*$) | (^[0-9]{10,}\t.*$)' foo` still no output. Please note there is tab in expression.

Comment: Don't put spaces around `|` if you don't want to use my second suggestion.

Comment: Just made an edit, forgot grep regular expressions don't like `\t` for tab.

Comment: Thanks, your second suggestion works. But If in some case I have to combine spaces with `|`, how to solve it?

Comment: Are you looking for a literal `|`? If you are, I have misunderstood the question. If not, I don't know why you would have to have spaces around it.

Comment: Thanks, I'm wrong, I misunderstood you, I think the spaces you said is like '\t' in regex expressions, now I know your mean is just remove space around `|` sign. e.g `egrep  $'^[0-9]{1,8}\t.*$|^[0-9]{10,}\t.*$' foo` works and do not need brackets